# Orbited: unauthorized connection

Tags: python, python-2.7, orbited

I have an issue with orbited in python 2.7 on Windows. I use orbited to proxy a websocket to the server that handles the requets.I get this error[image: the error]

this is my configuration file:

```
[global]
reactor=select
# reactor=kqueue
# reactor=epoll
proxy.enabled=1
session.ping_interval = 40
session.ping_timeout = 30
# once the sockets are open, orbited will drop its privileges to this user.
user=Administrator

[listen]
http://:8001
# uncomment to enable SSL on port 8043 using given .key and .crt files
#https://:8043
#
#[ssl]
#key=orbited.key
#crt=orbited.crt
#chain=orbited.chain

[static]

[access]
localhost:8000 -> localhost:3500
* -> localhost:3500

# new logging configuration using the python stdlib logging.fileConfig
[loggers]
keys = root,orbited,orbited_TCPConnectionResource

[handlers]
keys = console,errors,connections

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = NOTSET
handlers = console

[logger_orbited]
level = WARN
handlers = errors
qualname = orbited

[logger_orbited_TCPConnectionResource]
level = DEBUG
handlers = connections
qualname = orbited.cometsession.TCPConnectionResource

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = INFO
formatter = generic

[handler_errors]
class = FileHandler
args = ('error.log', 'w')
level = WARN
formatter = generic

[handler_connections]
class = FileHandler
level = DEBUG
formatter = generic
args = ('connections.log', 'w')

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s,%(msecs)03d %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
```

How can i fix that error?

Comment: `* -> 192.168.1.123:3500` in the `[access]` section should remove the warning. It might have security implications.